# string comparison function for generic C function

Tags: c, generics

```
void *idealGenericLSearch(void *key, void *base, int numElem, int elemSize,
                          int (*cmpfn)(void *, void *)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numElem; i++) {
        void *elemAddr = (char *)base + (i * elemSize);
        if (cmpfn(key, elemAddr) == 0)
            return elemAddr;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is the generic linear search function I am using. I am searching an array of `char *`s. Here is my comparison function:

```
int myStrCmp(void *vp1, void *vp2) {
    char *s1 = *(char**)vp1;
    char *s2 = *(char**)vp2;
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

Here is how I am calling it in main:

```
char *notes[] = { "Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D" };
char *keyNote = "Gb";
char **foundNote = idealGenericLSearch(&keyNote, notes, 5, sizeof(char *), myStrCmp);
if (foundNote) {
    printf("found the note: %s\n", *foundNote);
} else {
    printf("did not find note\n");
}
```

What I cannot figure out is why my comparison function still works the same if I get rid of the `(char**)` casts and the dereference. If I write the `cmpfn` like this:

```
int myStrCmp(void *vp1, void *vp2) {
    char *s1 = vp1;
    char *s2 = vp2;
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

it still works. When `lsearch` passes `elemAddr` to this comparison function, it should be a pointer to a `char*`, in which case inside the comparison function I would be passing `strcmp` `char**`s. Can someone explain what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is intriguing! One would expect some undefined behavior and even a crash.  It works by chance indeed, but for the following reasons:

You use string literals in your test:

```
char *notes[] = { "Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D" };
char *keyNote = "Gb";
```

There is a good chance the string literals are shared by your compiler, so the pointer in `notes[3]` has the same value as `keyNote`.

In your use linear search, so you will perform `strcmp`, not on the strings, but on their addresses. It is possible that the addresses contain a null byte and if your architecture is little endian, the significant non null bytes in the addresses will come first.  With all these chances, `strcmp((char*)notes[3], (char*)&keyNote)` would indeed be `0` and non `0` for all the other entries.

You can verify this theory by testing this:

```
char *notes[] = { "Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D" };
char *keyNote = strdup("Gb");
```

With a different pointer in `keyNote`, the generic search should fail.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tested it w/ strdup and you are right! I was thinking that It would be the same if dereferenced vp1 without the (char**), since it is coming in as a void**, but compiler wont allow that. so I deleted the * and ran it and it worked. That is how I became confused. thanks again

Comment: As Tom states also in his similar response, this is all undefined behavior, which sometimes happen to *work* as expected.  But it is comforting to have a rational explanation that may be accurate, or close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is why the second version of `myStrCmp` "works".  The first version is what you want, and it compares the strings as expected.  The second version, on the other hand, is treating the pointers that hold the addresses of the strings as strings themselves.  So it compares the pointers byte-by-byte as if they were strings.  If the pointers are different, then it will be likely to compare as unequal (unless both pointers contain zero bytes before they differ). But if the pointers are the same, then there's a chance they will compare equal if zero bytes are encountered, either in the pointers or after them, before differing bytes are encountered.

So why are the two `"Gb"` pointers the same?  Because the compiler recognizes that they are the same string, and allocates a single string for both references.

Needless to say, this is *very* undefined behavior, so analyzing why it sometimes works is purely academic.

Comment: thank you. looks like you basically said the same thing as chqrlie. I really appreciate it.